# C# Reflection Type.GetField array

Tags: c#, reflection, computer-science

Im trying to read variable array from string and show it in console but each time I run the program Im getting error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Can anyone suggest how to do this?

my code:

```
public class Positions
{
   public static string[] test = { "test", "test2" };
}

private void test()
{
   Positions pos = new Positions();

   Type type = typeof(Positions);
   FieldInfo fi = type.GetField("test[0]");

   Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(pos));
}
```

Comment: The field is `test`, not `test[0]` - you need to apply the index afterwards. Also, for static fields, you need to pass `null` as the target object

Comment: @MarcGravell ok, I changed last line to "Console.WriteLine(myFieldInfo.GetValue(null));" but where I should apply index?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
FieldInfo fi = type.GetField("test[0]");
```

Returns null. You don't have a field called `"test[0]"`. It is called `test`.

So, let us get it:

```
var fi = typeof(Positions).GetField(nameof(Positions.test));
```

And then read it:

<strike>`Positions pos = new Positions();`</strike>

It is static, we don't need an instance:

```
var fi = typeof(Positions).GetField(nameof(Positions.test))!; // We know it is not null
var value = fi.GetValue(null) as string[];
Console.WriteLine(value[0]); // value could be null
```

*The exclamation mark is to tell the analyzer that these are not null. No it does not magically make them not null. It just disables a warning. One that could be useful to you, by the way.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been trying to do this for several hours...

Comment: @mareklipka12 there are plenty of similar posts - https://www.bing.com/search?&q=c%23+reflection+array+index%20site:stackoverflow.com you don't really need to wait so long to find answer yourself.